# What does "are nines" mean in this context?

Tags: slang, numbers, humor, sexual-minorities

I stumbled upon some conversation on the TV show Desperate Housewives (Season 4, Episode 10) and I do not understand what the "nines" and "a three" indicate in the following context.

> Well, then you just have to fix him up with someone. Give him back his will to work.
>
> Yeah, about that. Most of our friends are nines, and Walter, we love him, but, kind of a three. And in the gay world, three does not go into nine.
>
> Well, we'll just have to find him someone who's not good at gay math.

Comment: On a scale of 1-10. See the film "10." And 3 into 9 is not a math hint.

Comment: Then that would be "**a** nine". "Being nine" means being 9 years of age.

Comment: @JohnLawler But the sentence needs a verb. What kind of verb is in *a nine*?

Comment: _Are_ is a verb (in this case, a 3rd person plural present tense verb). _Be_ is the auxiliary verb for predicate adjectives and predicate nouns, like _a nine_.

Answer (score 11):

It's common to rate people's qualities (beauty, wealth, personality, etc.) on a 10 point scale, with 10 being perfection and 0 or 1 being least desirable.

A "nine" is someone who is almost perfect, while a "three" is significantly worse than average.

"three does not go into nine" is a joke. In mathematics, "goes into" refers to being evenly divisible: since 9 is a multiple of 3, 3 goes into 9. But in reference to humans, they're using it as a euphemism for compatibility or sex: their beautiful friends aren't going to want to go out with a troll.